# Display Static Content through TableView in iOS / swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, segue

I have a section in my app where I would like to display static content that is divided in short chapters (mostly text and some figures), for example a manual. The questions is: what's the best way to do this?

[image]

I was thinking of a static TableViewController containing my chapters, which on click lead to a ViewController containing the actual content. However, having a segue for each of the TableView cells to my ViewController seems wrong. Also, what is the best way to embed the static content in my ViewController? The content consists (depending on the selected chapter) of text and figures, taken from a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a totally standard vanilla boring everyday 5-cent master-detail interface.

The thing that's wrong with your drawing is the use of multiple segues. You only need *one* segue — one that looks at *which* row was tapped and loads the data corresponding to *that* row into the view controller that is then instantiated and pushed onto the navigation controller.

If you create a new iPhone app from the Master-Detail template in Xcode, you'll see a standard setup for doing this sort of thing.

As to the question of static vs. dynamic, personally I'd recommend a normal code-based table data source for this. Your *data* may be static, but most table data is, ultimately; that doesn't mean you'd want to use a static table. The key is simply to store your data in a format that can be loaded at launch time and parsed quickly into a data structure that is precisely adapted to the way the data is to be displayed and related.